# Use multiple queries depending on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is there any way in oracle to write following logic, and where it's efficient to do it, in sql or pl/sql?:
If date equal to something than select from table1  if date more than something than select from table1 and table2? I was surfing here but didn't find good example.

There are two tables, table1 - monthly data, table2 -daily data.

For example:

If day >= max(day) from table1
than use following query

```
select sum(vol) from table1 where day between trunc(day,'year') and             
last_day(trunc(day,month)) and code='test1'
```

if day < max(day) from table1

```
select sum(vol) from
(
select day, vol from table1 where code='test1'
union all
select day, max(case when code = 'test1' then vol else  null end )) vol           
 from test2
  where day between add_months(last_day(trunc(sysdate, 'month')),-1)  and last_day(trunc(sysdate,month)) 
       and (to_char(day+1,'DD') ='01') and code='test1'
)
  where day between trunc(day,'year') and last_day(trunc(day,month))
```

thanks

Comment: Need more specifics on what you're trying to do and what you've tried.

Comment: As @L.ScottJohnson stated, please provide additional info and what you've tried so far. In addition to that, providing some example data from the two tables would also make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I tried to put more detail

Comment: Tony in the second query you provided, there is a `test2` table.  Is this intended to be `table2`?  It would useful in the subqueries to see how things fit together with the question.  I didn't see any reference in the conditions or queries to `table2`.  Thanks

Comment: 1. When you say `day> max(day)` , where is `day` coming from? Are you passing it via an input parameter? Or is it coming via table1. Then do you wish to run select statements for each row?  2. In PLSQL, standalone select statement is of no use without `into` clause or without using it via a cursor. What are you planning to do with `sum(vol)`?

Comment: Day is passing though input parameter

Comment: Sorry, test2 is table2